# Setar valor inputmask jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou construindo um pequeno sistema em jquery e na parte da edição onde necessito informar um valor de forma programática para o campo o JQuery InputMask não fica de forma correta. Abaixo o exemplo do meu código e do ocorrido na tela.

```
$(".money")
        .inputmask('numeric',{"autoUnmask": true,
            radixPoint:",",
            groupSeparator: ".",
            allowMinus: false,
            prefix: 'R$ ',            
            digits: 2,
            digitsOptional: false,
            rightAlign: true,
            unmaskAsNumber: true
        });

<div class="form-group">
     <label>Valor:</label>
     <input type="text" value="0" id="value" class="form-control money watch" required>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Edit 1
Como solicitado nos comentários como estou fazendo para colocar o valor no campo.
PS Este trigger eu consegui de um comentário no github informando que funcionava, já tentei com input também e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: @Sam pronto! Obrigado por responder!

Comment: Desculpe amigo, mas provavelmente você não deve ter entendido, mas tudo bem. Nas imagens, coloquei as setas e as linhas para ajudar. Não vejo como clarificar mais o que está havendo. Tenho o campo com id *VALUE* que está sendo configurado com inputmask. Porém, quando informo o valor do campo com val() ele ignora o . do valor como mostrado na primeira imagem.

Comment: Eu não sou novo aqui, sei como a comunidade funciona e que você deve explicar ao máximo a sua pergunta, pesquisei muito antes de vir perguntar por pessoas como você. Eu não tenho problema nenhum em editar a pergunta ou responder mais coisas, e como pode ver a imagem tem 150.6 e no campo ele fica 1506 ignorando completamente o **.**

Comment: Não jovem, acredito que o senhor seja experiente e que possa me ajudar, porém, o val() está na segunda imagem. O segundo metodo é o val() e logo após é o trigger que foi indicado nesta publicação do github https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/issues/261#issuecomment-71181680. E como havia dito o valor aparece errado na terceira imagem, assim que eu chamo o val para informa-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu entendi o seu problema, porque, quando manda uma valor com ponto, ***exemplo***: **150.6** considera `R$ 1506,00` e deveria ser: `R$ 150,60`, então tem como setar corretamente da seguinte forma, trocando o ponto por virgula no retorno, assim:

```
value.val(object.value.replace('.',','));
```

que vai funcionar, exemplo:

```js
$(".money").inputmask('numeric',
{   autoUnmask: true,
    radixPoint:",",
    groupSeparator: ".",
    allowMinus: true,
    prefix: 'R$ ',            
    digits: 2,
    digitsOptional: false,
    rightAlign: true,
    unmaskAsNumber: true
});
$("#BtnSetaValor").click(function(){
  $(".money").val('150.6'.replace('.',','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
     <label>Valor:</label>
     <input type="text" value="0" id="value" class="form-control money watch" required>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Seta Valor" id="BtnSetaValor" />
</div>
```

Talvez seja uma limitação ou até um `bug` e o que é bom fazer, [abrir um issue](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues) e relatar o problema para a comunidade tentar resolver.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado. Não sei se é um bug, talvez seja uma pequena limitação quanto a configuração que foi passada inicialmente. Mas obrigado jovem!

Comment: @MárcioEric é bom relatar no git, se quiser é claro ... mas, que bom funcionou